# Sending data to RESTful web services from iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, rest

I am facing a challenge to upload & download data, to and from the server using RESTful web services.

Is it possible to use a RESTful service client, if possible any way to achieve that in an iOS app to send data to the service.

Comment: Yes, that's possible and supported by a number of public frameworks. Did you bother using Google before asking here?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay,i seen many blogs but  i didnt find straight output to post or receive data using the rest services.Not even to possible or not also.

Comment: This old question can be closed as Needs More Focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ajay: As Claus mentioned there are number of public frameworks/wrappers are there, you can use them for RESTful service interaction from your code. The one I frequently use is `ASIHttpRequest`, quite handy and easy to use. There are enough examples out there with `ASIHttpRequest`you can use it as reference.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i will proceed with ASIHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear. Do you need to push data from the server to the iOS app using a REST service?
If so, REST does not provide an interface for push. (It only provides a client->server Create/Read/Update/Delete API).

Comment: Thanks for your reply,with the request from the app only i need to post or get data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASIHTTPRequest or use RestKit for some more advanced stuff!

RestKit works really nice!